# GraphQL - Execution Error (The parent cannot be cast to..)

Tags: graphql, dapper, asp.net-core-5.0, hotchocolate

I am trying to implement GraphQL in web API. The method is working fine when return object type. But it is throwing an error while I am trying to return Object List.

```
    public class MyData
    {
       public int Code { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string State { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
   }
```

Query.cs

```
     public List<MyData> GetList()
     {
         List<MyData> myList = null;

         string query = "select Code, Name, LastName,  City, State, Country from MyTable";

         using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
              myList = connection.Query<MyData>(query).ToList();
          }
          return myList;
      }

    public class QueryObjectType : ObjectType<Query>
    {
         descriptor.Field(g => g.GetList())
        .Type<MyDataDataObjectType>().Name("GetList");
    }
    
    public class MyDataDataObjectType: ObjectType<MyData>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<MyData> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(g => g.Code).Type<IntType>().Name("Code");
            descriptor.Field(g => g.Name).Type<StringType>().Name("Name");
            descriptor.Field(g => g.LastName).Type<StringType>().Name("LastName");
            descriptor.Field(g => g.City).Type<StringType>().Name("City");
            descriptor.Field(g => g.State).Type<IntType>().Name("State");
            descriptor.Field(g => g.Country).Type<IntType>().Name("Country");
         }
    }
```

startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType<QueryObjectType>();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
            app.UseGraphQLVoyager(new VoyagerOptions()
            {
                GraphQLEndPoint = "/graphql"
        }, "/graphql-ui");
    }
```

The GetList() methods is returning the list with object data of type MyData. But in the  Insomnia client showing an error. I think something wrong with the below code

```
         descriptor.Field(g => g.GetList())
        .Type<MyDataDataObjectType>().Name("GetList");
```

I am sending the following in the POST call

```
query{
      a:GetList
      {
         Code
       }
     }
```

Error:

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
> "locations": [
> {
> "line": 4,
> "column": 4
> }
> ],
> "path": [
> "a",
> "Code"
> ],
> "extensions": {
> "message": "The parent cannot be cast to MyData.",
> "stackTrace": "   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.MiddlewareContext.SourceT\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.MiddlewareContext.ParentT\r\n   at lambda_method65(Closure , IResolverContext )\r\n   at HotChocolate.Types.FieldMiddlewareCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
> }
> }
> ],
> "data": {
> "a": {
> "Code": null
> }
> }
> }

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be seeing an exception in the server that would've told you what is wrong.
What I can see is that the type of the field you are specifying is wrong. When returning a List you need to use the `ListType`:

```cs
descriptor.Field(g => g.GetList())
        .Type<ListType<MyDataDataObjectType>>().Name("GetList");
```

[Learn more about this in the lists documentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/lists)

Comment: Thanks, again getting the same error, something wrong with my implementation. Let me understand the documentation